# Unable to render the wall as shown in the image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dijkstra, path-finding

I am trying to implement the Path Finding Visualizer by following the Youtube video. I have made a little changes as I was getting some errors. The errors are now gone but the wall is not getting rendered. I think the mouse functionality is not getting implemented properly. Can you please take a look at it? You can also take a look at the entire code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-hertz-mrwsg7?file=/src/

These are my files:

PathfindingVisualizer.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Node from './Node/Node';
import './Node/Node.css'
import './PathfindingVisualizer.css';
import { dijkstra_algorithm as dijkstra, getNodesInShortestPathOrder } from '../algorithms/dijkstra'

const START_NODE_ROW = 10;
const START_NODE_COL = 15;
const FINISH_NODE_ROW = 15;
const FINISH_NODE_COL = 30;

export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      grid: [],
      animatedGrid: [],
      mouseIsPressed: false
    };

    // Bind the event handlers in the constructor
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseEnter = this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const grid = getInitialGrid();
    this.setState({
      grid,
      animatedGrid: structuredClone(grid) // passing a deepcopy of the grid
    });
  }

  handleMouseDown(row, col) {
    const newGrid = getNewGridWithWallToggled(this.state.grid, row, col);
    if (newGrid) {
      this.setState({ grid: newGrid, mouseIsPressed: true });
    }
  }
  
  handleMouseEnter(row, col) {
    if (!this.state.mouseIsPressed) return;
    const newGrid = getNewGridWithWallToggled(this.state.grid, row, col);
    if (newGrid) {
      this.setState({ grid: newGrid });
    }
  }
  

  handleMouseUp() {
    this.setState({ mouseIsPressed: false });
  }

  animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder) {
    visitedNodesInOrder.forEach((node, i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const newGrid = prevState.animatedGrid;
          const newNode = {
            ...node,
            isVisited: true,
          };
          newGrid[node.row][node.col] = newNode;
          return { grid: newGrid };
        });
      }, 20 * i);
    });
  }

  visualizeDijkstra() {
    const { grid } = this.state;
    const startNode = grid[START_NODE_ROW][START_NODE_COL];
    const finishNode = grid[FINISH_NODE_ROW][FINISH_NODE_COL];
    const visitedNodesInOrder = dijkstra(grid, startNode, finishNode);
    this.animateDijkstra(visitedNodesInOrder);
  }

  render() {
    const { animatedGrid, mouseIsPressed } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => this.visualizeDijkstra()}>
          Visualize Dijkstra Algorithm
        </button>
        <div className="grid">
          {animatedGrid.map((row, rowIdx) => {
            return (
              <div key={rowIdx}>
                {row.map((node, nodeIdx) => {
                  const { isStart, isFinish, isVisited, isWall } = node;
                  return (
                    <Node
                      key={nodeIdx}
                      isStart={isStart}
                      isFinish={isFinish}
                      isVisited={isVisited}
                      isWall={isWall}
                      mouseIsPressed={mouseIsPressed}
                      onMouseDown={() => this.handleMouseDown(row, nodeIdx)}
                      onMouseEnter={(row, col) => this.handleMouseEnter(row, col)}
                      onMouseUp={() => this.handleMouseUp()}
                      row={row} // Pass row prop
                      //col={col} // Pass col prop
                    >
                    </Node>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const getInitialGrid = () => {
    const grid = [];
  
    for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
      const currentRow = [];
      for (let col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
        currentRow.push(createNode(col, row));
      }
      grid.push(currentRow);
    }
    return grid;
  };
  

  function getNewGridWithWallToggled(grid, row, col) {
    const newGrid = grid.map((gridRow, rowIndex) =>
      gridRow.map((node, colIndex) => {
        if (rowIndex === row && colIndex === col) {
          return {
            ...node,
            isWall: !node.isWall
          };
        }
        return node;
      })
    );
    return newGrid;
  }
  
  

const createNode = (col, row) => {
  return {
    col,
    row,
    isStart: row === START_NODE_ROW && col === START_NODE_COL,
    isFinish: row === FINISH_NODE_ROW && col === FINISH_NODE_COL,
    distance: Infinity,
    isVisited: false,
    isWall:false,
    previousNode: null,
  };
};
```

This is node.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './Node.css';

export default class Node extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      isFinish,
      isStart,
      isVisited,
      isWall,
      onMouseDown,
      onMouseEnter,
      onMouseUp,
      row,
      col
    } = this.props;

    let extraClassName = "";
    if (isFinish) {
      extraClassName = "node-finish";
    } else if (isStart) {
      extraClassName = "node-start";
    } else if (isVisited) {
      extraClassName = "node-visited";
    } else if (isWall) {
      extraClassName = "node-wall";
    }

    return (
      <div
        id={`node-${row}-${col}`}
        className={`node ${extraClassName}`}
        onMouseDown={() => onMouseDown(row, col)}
        onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter(row, col)}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
      ></div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the node, nothing happens. But I want something like this wall. I will attach the image for your reference:

[image]